# What are the functions of an array of an arrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I tried to do:

```
static boolean newTrait(ArrayList<Integer> population, int[] traits) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 625; j++) {
                if(traits[j].equals(population[i].get(i))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The java compiler said that I had an "unresolved compiler issue."

Can anyone help?

Comment: `traits[j]` returns an a primitive integer. Primitives have no methods at all.

Comment: You want `if(traits[j] == population.get(i))`. The boxed `Integer` returned from the list will be automatically unboxed into a primitive int for the purpose of the comparison.

Comment: You probably wanted to write ```if``` conditon as ```if(population.get(i).equals(traits[j])) {``` or ```if(traits[j] == population.get(i)) {```

Answer (score 1):

`[X]` operator is for arrays. You don't have an `ArrayList` array you just have an `ArrayList<>` which, although it has "Array" in the name, is not an array and so cannot be accessed with [X]. `ArrayList` is an object with regular methods.

It's perfectly valid to have an `ArrayList` array 
e.g.

```
static boolean newTrait(ArrayList<Integer>[] population, int[] traits)
```

where each element in the `population` array IS A `ArrayList`. In which case you would first need to access the element in the array (via `[X]`) and then access the elements IN the `ArrayList` using `get()`

e.g. get the first element of the array

```
 ArrayList<Integer> firstList = population[0];
```

then get the Xth item in the list 
e.g.

```
 firstList.get(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

All simple types (not objects) do not have any methods. In your case neither the array not the int values inside the array have methods.

Fix:

```
if(traits[j] == population.get(i)) 
{
    return false;
}
```

This compares an `int` on the left side with an `Integer` on the right side. For `int` the `==` operator is correct but it would be wrong for `Integers`. However in this case the compiler does automatically 'unbox' the `Integer` on the right side to `int`.

Notice that I removed the wrong `[i]` after population as well. Population is not an array.